# flex 4 remove Rotate easing

Tags: apache-flex, image, flex4, rotation, easing-functions

I'm trying to animate (rotate) an image in flex4 but it seems that flex is adding easing to my animation by default. How can I over ride this so my rotate doesn't have any easing.

Here the line of code I'm using

```
<s:Rotate angleFrom="0" angleTo="1080" duration="10000" autoCenterTransform="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set the [easer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Animate.html#easer) property of the Rotation so that it is [linear](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/easing/Linear.html).